# Passar parâmetros para o Controller através do @Html.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso renderizar uma View dentro de outra, mas essa View renderizada precisa receber e exibir dados do banco, então vou utilizar o @Html.Action para isso, mas preciso passar um parâmetro para o método no controller buscar os dados no banco com base nesse parâmetro e rederizar a View com os dados. O problema é que do jeito que fiz o parâmetro não é passado, sempre fica null.

View:

```
    @Html.Action("ExibirCliente", "Cliente", new {idcliente = Model.ID})
```

Controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ExibirCliente(int idcidade)
    {
        Cliente c = new Cliente();
         c = c.BuscarCliente(idcidade);
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_ViewCLiente.cshtml", cep);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O parâmetro passado no objeto anônimo tem que ser exatamente o mesmo na assinatura da *Action*. Veja que:

```
@Html.Action("ExibirCliente", "Cliente", new {idcliente = Model.ID})
```

O parâmetro é `idcliente`, enquanto que na *Action*:

```
public ActionResult ExibirCliente(int idcidade)
```

Obviamente o *Model Binder* não fará a correlação e o parâmetro será nulo.

Agora, se você modificar para:

```
@Html.Action("ExibirCliente", "Cliente", new {idcidade = Model.ID})
```

Vai funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, eu sabia que os nomes tinham que ser o mesmo, mas repassei passo a passo o código e não vi o nome diferente da variavel.... que mancada rsrs obrigado, agora obviamento funcionou...

Answer (score 4):

O nome do parâmetro na View e na Controller deve ser o mesmo, por isso você só está recebendo `null`. Basta você alterar sua View para

```
@Html.Action("ExibirCliente", "Cliente", new {idcidade = Model.ID})
```

já que seu Controller espera receber um parâmetro chamado `idcidade`.